# Passing Javascript DOM Value to Inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i need to get some value from one hidden id and pass it to another ID as inner HTML.

here my code

```
<script>
function replaceText(){
var x=document.getElementById("mainTitle1").value;
document.getElementById("mainTitle").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Here HTML File

```
<span id="mainTitle"></span>

<span style="display:none;" id="mainTitle1">Text Content</span>
```

but this isn't working. I'm getting 'undefined'

Comment: `span` elements don’t have a `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function replaceText(){
var x=document.getElementById("mainTitle1").innerHTML;   //Correct here 
document.getElementById("mainTitle").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

The Problem is with `.value` change it to `.innerHTML`

Comment: `GetElementById` what is this?

Comment: fetching the tag with the particular id from the HTML

Comment: @Girish Sorry my mistake.. fixed it. but still getting 'undefined'

Comment: @ChathuraLakmal..try using innerhtml instead of value

Comment: @ChathuraLakmal `value` is working with `form` elements.. you should use there `innerHTML` or `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementById` should be `getElementById` JavaScript is case sensitive language

Comment: I'm getting Undefined in this field <span id="mainTitle"></span>

Comment: @ChathuraLakmal `value` is working with `form` elements.. you should use there `innerHTML` or `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

easy :

```
var x=document.getElementById("mainTitle1").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("mainTitle").innerHTML=x;
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AziziMusa/hyyj0vLc/1/)